# Change Sort Order

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, layout

How to change the products sort order from "desc" to "asc" for one particular category?

Is it possible with layout xml?

Answer (score 2):

May be something will work for you, just put this code in your category layout update area.

```
<reference name="product_list"> 
   <action method="setDefaultDirection">
            <string>desc</string>
   </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change order for particular category you can do something like,

1. Overwrite the toolbar block form \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php
2. Check for the function "`getCurrentDirection()`"
3. Under this function you can put your condition with particular categoryID, if you fond that particular category set `$dir` to "desc" and `return $dir`

that all.

There might be some other way to do this. For time I found this one. This will 100% work for you.